# How to generate N X N table using jquery templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I have to generate N X N table
suppose if I give N as 5, it should create a table with 5 rows and columns. 
My first plan to create an HTML in a foor loop, but I believe that using jQuery templates , its possible to generate table, which is faster than the other one.Please correct me if I am wrong.

This is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
//sample data
                var data = [
                             [
                                { Row: 0, Col: 0 },
                                { Row: 0, Col: 1 }
                             ],
                             [
                                { Row: 1, Col: 0 },
                                { Row: 1, Col: 1 }
                             ]
                        ];

                $('#trTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#containerTable');
                $('#testArea').html(generateNNJSON(2, 2));
                $('#testSection').html(data);
                $('#trTemplate').tmpl(generateNNJSON(2, 2)).appendTo('#tblArena');

            });
// generate JSON
            function generateNNJSON(row, col) {

                var JSONdata = '[';
                for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    JSONdata += '[';
                    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                        JSONdata += '{ Row:' + i + ',Col:' + j + ' }';
                        if (!(j == col - 1))
                            JSONdata += ',';
                    }
                    if (!(i == row - 1))
                        JSONdata += '],';
                    else
                        JSONdata += ']';
                }
                JSONdata += ']';
                return JSONdata;
            }


        </script>
```

This is my HTML

```
<script id="trTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
           <tr>   
            {{each $data}}            
              <td>${Col}</td>
            {{/each}}
            </tr>

    </script>
    <table id="containerTable" border="2">
    </table>
    <table id="tblArena" border="2">
    </table>
    <div id="testArea">
    </div>
    <div id="testSection">

    </div>
```

While viewing this page only `$('#trTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#containerTable');` is working and the data will be like this '[[{ Row:0,Col:0 },{ Row:0,Col:1 }],[{ Row:1,Col:0 },{ Row:1,Col:1 }]]'

`generateNNJSON` will returns like this `[object Object],[object Object][object Object],[object Object]`

So only the first table is created and second is empty.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data parameter of `$.tmpl()` must be an `object`, you have to convert JSON string to an object:

```
function generateNNJSON(row, col) {
  var JSONdata = '[';
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    JSONdata += '[';
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      JSONdata += '{ "Row":' + i + ',"Col":' + j + ' }';
      if (!(j == col - 1))
        JSONdata += ',';
    }
    if (!(i == row - 1))
      JSONdata += '],';
    else
      JSONdata += ']';
  }
  JSONdata += ']';
  return $.parseJSON(JSONdata);
}
```